Transfer media pipe pose landmark data to 3d model
I used media pipe's Pose landmark detection python library to get the pose data from a video and saved it to a json file. I'm using WebSockets to stream the pose data and trying to apply it to the 3d model armature. The data streaming and acceptance work properly. I'm fairly new to Blender so I might have missed a simple detail. As I try to apply the pose data to the 3d model via blender scripting, the blender console prints: Moved bone 'mixamorig:LeftUpLeg' to (0.608, 0.44, 0) Moved bone 'mixamorig:RightUpLeg' to (0.593, 0.442, 0) Moved bone 'mixamorig:LeftLeg' to (0.612, 0.51, 0) Moved bone 'mixamorig:RightLeg' to (0.62, 0.515, 0) Moved bone 'mixamorig:LeftFoot' to (0.594, 0.581, 0) Moved bone 'mixamorig:RightFoot' to (0.659, 0.592, 0) but no visual changes are happening on the 3d model except the model is very slightly vibrating. I have not messed with scaling as the 3d model and media pipe's settings when capturing the pose data were at scale 1. What could be the Issue?
Blender Python code:
import bpy
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import threading

# Bone mapping for Blender armature
bone_mapping = {
    "LEFT_SHOULDER": "mixamorig:LeftShoulder",
    "RIGHT_SHOULDER": "mixamorig:RightShoulder",
    "LEFT_ELBOW": "mixamorig:LeftForeArm",
    "RIGHT_ELBOW": "mixamorig:RightForeArm",
    "LEFT_WRIST": "mixamorig:LeftHand",
    "RIGHT_WRIST": "mixamorig:RightHand",
    "LEFT_HIP": "mixamorig:LeftUpLeg",
    "RIGHT_HIP": "mixamorig:RightUpLeg",
    "LEFT_KNEE": "mixamorig:LeftLeg",
    "RIGHT_KNEE": "mixamorig:RightLeg",
    "LEFT_ANKLE": "mixamorig:LeftFoot",
    "RIGHT_ANKLE": "mixamorig:RightFoot"
}

# Apply pose data to the Blender armature
def apply_pose_to_armature(pose_data):
    def update_armature():
        armature = bpy.data.objects.get("Armature")
        if not armature:
            print("Armature not found!")
            return

        # Ensure the armature is set as the active object and switch to pose mode
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = armature
        if bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.type == 'ARMATURE':
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')

            for landmark in pose_data:
                name = landmark["name"]
                x, y = landmark["x"], landmark["y"]
                bone_name = bone_mapping.get(name)

                if bone_name:
                    try:
                        bone = armature.pose.bones[bone_name]
                        bone.matrix_basis.translation = (x / 1000, y / 1000, 0)  # Scale
                        print(f"Moved bone '{bone_name}' to ({x / 1000}, {y / 1000}, 0)")
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f"Bone '{bone_name}' not found in armature.")
                else:
                    print(f"No mapping found for landmark '{name}'.")

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')  # Switch back to object mode
        else:
            print("Active object is not an armature!")

    # Schedule the update on the main thread
    bpy.app.timers.register(update_armature)

# WebSocket client to receive pose data
async def receive_pose_data():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:5000") as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            pose_data = json.loads(message)
            apply_pose_to_armature(pose_data)

# Start WebSocket client
def start_websocket_client():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(receive_pose_data())

# Run WebSocket client in a separate thread
threading.Thread(target=start_websocket_client, daemon=True).start()

Media pipe pose detection script:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import json
import asyncio
import websockets

class poseDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, smooth=True, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.smooth = smooth
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.pTime = 0

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(static_image_mode=self.mode,
                                smooth_landmarks=self.smooth,
                                min_detection_confidence=self.detectionCon,
                                min_tracking_confidence=self.trackCon)

    def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, self.results.pose_landmarks, self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def getPosition(self, img):
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(self.results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
        return self.lmList

    def showFps(self, img):
        cTime = time.time()
        fbs = 1 / (cTime - self.pTime)
        self.pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fbs)), (70, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 0), 3)

def get_landmark_names():
    return [
        "NOSE", "LEFT_EYE_INNER", "LEFT_EYE", "LEFT_EYE_OUTER", "RIGHT_EYE_INNER", "RIGHT_EYE", "RIGHT_EYE_OUTER",
        "LEFT_EAR", "RIGHT_EAR", "MOUTH_LEFT", "MOUTH_RIGHT", "LEFT_SHOULDER", "RIGHT_SHOULDER", "LEFT_ELBOW",
        "RIGHT_ELBOW", "LEFT_WRIST", "RIGHT_WRIST", "LEFT_PINKY", "RIGHT_PINKY", "LEFT_INDEX", "RIGHT_INDEX",
        "LEFT_THUMB", "RIGHT_THUMB", "LEFT_HIP", "RIGHT_HIP", "LEFT_KNEE", "RIGHT_KNEE", "LEFT_ANKLE", "RIGHT_ANKLE",
        "LEFT_HEEL", "RIGHT_HEEL", "LEFT_FOOT_INDEX", "RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX"
    ]

async def send_pose_data(video_path, websocket, output_file):
    detector = poseDetector()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)  # Use video file
    landmark_names = get_landmark_names()
    all_pose_data = []

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        img = detector.findPose(img)
        lmList = detector.getPosition(img)
        detector.showFps(img)
        named_lmList = [{ "name": landmark_names[id], "x": cx, "y": cy } for id, cx, cy in lmList]
        all_pose_data.append(named_lmList)
        data = json.dumps(named_lmList)
        await websocket.send(data)  # Send pose data to WebSocket
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(all_pose_data, f)

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

async def handler(websocket):
    video_path = "trainee/videos/model_1.mp4"
    output_file = "pose_data.json"
    await send_pose_data(video_path, websocket, output_file)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "0.0.0.0", 5000):
        await asyncio.Future()  # Run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


I'm working on something similar. I think this project might help you to understand how to do this using armatures, but I haven't been able to reproduce this on my own: https://github.com/cgtinker/BlendArMocap/blob/main/src/cgt_transfer/cgt_tf_object_properties.py
One problem I think you are experiencing based on your description is due to hierarchical way bones or organized in blender, there might be some way to resolve this but I haven't figured it out yet. The output we're getting from mediapipe is absolute, so I found it easier to just import the point data as an empty object for each point. Here is the script I used:
import bpy
import json

# Path to the Mediapipe JSON file
json_file_path = "./output.json"

# Open and parse the JSON file
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
    animation_data = json.load(file)

# Names for the points based on Mediapipe documentation
point_names = [
    "WRIST", "THUMB_CMC", "THUMB_MCP", "THUMB_IP", "THUMB_TIP",
    "INDEX_FINGER_MCP", "INDEX_FINGER_PIP", "INDEX_FINGER_DIP", "INDEX_FINGER_TIP",
    "MIDDLE_FINGER_MCP", "MIDDLE_FINGER_PIP", "MIDDLE_FINGER_DIP", "MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP",
    "RING_FINGER_MCP", "RING_FINGER_PIP", "RING_FINGER_DIP", "RING_FINGER_TIP",
    "PINKY_MCP", "PINKY_PIP", "PINKY_DIP", "PINKY_TIP"
]

# Create an empty object for each point
empty_objects = []
for i, name in enumerate(point_names):
    empty = bpy.data.objects.new(name, None)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(empty)
    empty.empty_display_size = 0.02
    empty.empty_display_type = 'SPHERE'
    empty_objects.append(empty)

# Animate the empty objects
frame_number = 1
for frame_data in animation_data:
    landmarks = frame_data[0]  # Get the first hand data in the frame
    for idx, coords in enumerate(landmarks):
        x, y, z = coords  # Mediapipe landmarks are normalized; adjust if needed.
        empty = empty_objects[idx]
        empty.location = (x, y, z)
        empty.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_number)
    frame_number += 1

print("Empty objects created and animation data imported successfully!")

